# Wildfly: How to configure worker threads in IO subsystem dynamically

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly, wildfly-8

I want to dynamically configure following section in wildfly-8.2.0 in standalone.xml:

```
<worker name="default" io-threads="100" task-max-threads="100"/>
```

Basically I don't want these values to be hardcoded and calculate them at the time of server startup and pass them as jboss boot parameters. I did something like this:

```
 <worker name="default" io-threads="${my.io.threads:100}" task-max-threads="${my.task.max.threads:1000}"/>
```

I am passing these parameters as **-Dmy.io.threads** and **-Dmy.task.max.threads** while starting wildfly server. But it's failing to parse standalone.xml with following exception:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:112) [wildfly-controller-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:331) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:259) [wildfly-controller-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${my.io.threads:100}"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at org.jboss.dmr.StringModelValue.asInt(StringModelValue.java:139) [jboss-dmr-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.dmr.ModelNode.asInt(ModelNode.java:240) [jboss-dmr-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AttributeParser.parse(AttributeParser.java:116) [wildfly-controller-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AttributeParser.parse(AttributeParser.java:82) [wildfly-controller-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AttributeParser$DiscardOldDefaultValueParser.parse(AttributeParser.java:177) [wildfly-controller-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AttributeParser.parseAndSetParameter(AttributeParser.java:61) [wildfly-controller-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.PersistentResourceXMLDescription.parse(PersistentResourceXMLDescription.java:83) [wildfly-controller-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.PersistentResourceXMLDescription.parseChildren(PersistentResourceXMLDescription.java:135) [wildfly-controller-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.PersistentResourceXMLDescription.parse(PersistentResourceXMLDescription.java:107) [wildfly-controller-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.io.IOSubsystemParser_1_0.readElement(IOSubsystemParser_1_0.java:71)
    at org.wildfly.extension.io.IOSubsystemParser_1_0.readElement(IOSubsystemParser_1_0.java:41)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.parseServerProfile(StandaloneXml.java:1131) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readServerElement_1_4(StandaloneXml.java:458) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:145) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:107) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:104) [wildfly-controller-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    ... 3 more
```

I have read that IO subsystem doesn't support expressions. Is there any other way to achieve this? Is there any internal parameter which when passed at boot time would override these values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wildfly-8.2.0 doesn't support expressions for `io-threads` and `task-max-threads` attributes in worker section of IO subsystem. I have raised a [Jira ticket](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-1622) under WFCORE project to have this addressed by Jboss team.

Answer (score 3):

Since it doesn't support expressions there is no way to dynamically configure it. However in [WildFly 10.0.0.Final](https://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/10.0.0.Final/subsystem/io/worker/index.html) it is dynamically generated if left empty.

> Specify the number of I/O threads to create for the worker. If not specified, a default will be chosen, which is calculated by cpuCount * 2